# Slider On/Off Switch in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am looking for a WPF tutorial on creating a slide ON/OFF switch like on the iPhone.

Here is an example (the "Send all traffic" option) https://secure-tunnel.com/support/software_setup/iphone/images/iphone_vpn_settings.jpg

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I haven't seen a tutorial on this exact problem, but i guess you can start by launching Expression Blend and putting a CheckBox on it. Then select the CheckBox, go to main menu - Object -> Edit Style -> Edit a Copy

This will make Blend generate the default style of CheckBox so you're able to modify it. Look at how things work there and you'll be able to achieve some results.

Basically (besides colors and brushes stuff) you'll need to look at triggers hooked up to the IsChecked property.
E.g. when IsChecked is True you move the rectangle to one of the sides, show the ON word and hide the OFF word. To animate this you only need to add trigger in- and out- animations.

UPD:
I've spent 10-15 minutes in blend to make a "prototype":

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="CheckBoxIPhone.Window1"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="Window1"
    Width="320" 
    Height="240" 
    FontFamily="Segoe UI" 
    FontSize="20" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    >

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="OnChecking">
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="slider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="25"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="OnUnchecking">
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="slider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="slider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)">
                                    <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
                                </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                        <DockPanel x:Name="dockPanel">
                            <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Grid Margin="5,5,0,5" Width="50" Background="#FFC0CCD9">
                                <TextBlock Text="ON" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,3,0"/>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,0,0,0" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Text="OFF" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="slider" Width="23" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="3,3,3,3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="1,1,1,1">
                                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                                                <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                                                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </Border.RenderTransform>
                                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF4490FF" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF8AB4FF" Offset="1"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFD1E2FF" Offset="0"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                        </DockPanel>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnUnchecking}" x:Name="OnUnchecking_BeginStoryboard"/>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnChecking}" x:Name="OnChecking_BeginStoryboard"/>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStyle1}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="CheckBox"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm also suggesting you to read about Styles and Templates in WPF if you're interested.

Comment: Would a two value (0 and 1) slider not work?

Maybe style the slide to a block half the width and the full hight of the control. 0 = OFF, 1 = ON. just a case of getting the text behind the slider. 

Only thinking this as the slide animation I assume would be easier to achieve.

Please bare in mind I am very much a newbie and have not idea how to do what I just said :-)

Kevin.

Comment: i think checkbox is better because it IS the control that can have two states ON and OFF (actually there's also NULL, but we're not interested in it now :) ). But how these ON and OFF look is irrelevant. That's the idea of templating in WPF.

Comment: I suppose the reason I was suggesting the slider was its the closest visually to what I want to achieve and it does contain the functionality, albeit slightly differently to the checkbox, that I need. I looked that the checkbox style template and was quite daunting when trying to figure out what to change to get this slider effect.

Comment: Cheers, I will have a play with your prototype. I have been reading through MS documentation.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: <selfishness=on>don't forget to vote up and accept if it answers your question<selfishness=off> :)

Comment: Cant vote up yet
Need more points or something. But big Kudos to you for taking the time to help me. It is truly appreciated.

Comment: Can we build a toggle button with more than two states ? Scenarios such as when data needs to be shown for various periods such as Day/Week/Month/year. It can be easily done with a dropdown, but if we can show all the options together and able to switch, it would be great.

Comment: is the `ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames` necessary in the above code? It is being used to changed the `Margin`. I don't see the significance!!

Comment: here is a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/AnweshGangula/WPF-Slider-Toggle) I created using this a reference

Answer (score 61):

I created some styles based on the post by arconaut in orange and blue.

Screenshot:   [image: click]

I wanted my style to closer match the On/Off Switch style of iOS devices. One difference in this style is, that the sliding animation does only slide the switch and not the indicators below. Maybe if i can find some time I will modify it that way. Until then I want to share my result. It's not perfect, but here is the code.

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CheckedBlue" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
  <GradientStop Color="#FF285AB3" Offset="0" />
  <GradientStop Color="#FF4184EC" Offset="0.5" />
  <GradientStop Color="#FF558BED" Offset="0.5" />
  <GradientStop Color="#FF7DACF0" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CheckedOrange" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
  <GradientStop Color="#FFCA6A13" Offset="0" />
  <GradientStop Color="#FFF67D0C" Offset="0.2" />
  <GradientStop Color="#FFFE7F0C" Offset="0.2" />
  <GradientStop Color="#FFFA8E12" Offset="0.5" />
  <GradientStop Color="#FFFF981D" Offset="0.5" />
  <GradientStop Color="#FFFCBC5A" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckedOrangeBorder" Color="#FF8E4A1B" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckedBlueBorder" Color="#FF143874" />
<Style x:Key="OrangeSwitchStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}" />
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
          <Storyboard x:Key="OnChecking">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="slider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
              <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="53" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          </Storyboard>
          <Storyboard x:Key="OnUnchecking">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="slider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
              <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="0" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          </Storyboard>
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <DockPanel x:Name="dockPanel">
          <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
          <Grid>
            <Border x:Name="BackgroundBorder" BorderBrush="#FF939393" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" Height="27" Width="94">
              <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                  <GradientStop Color="#FFB5B5B5" Offset="0" />
                  <GradientStop Color="#FFDEDEDE" Offset="0.1" />
                  <GradientStop Color="#FFEEEEEE" Offset="0.5" />
                  <GradientStop Color="#FFFAFAFA" Offset="0.5" />
                  <GradientStop Color="#FFFEFEFE" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
              </Border.Background>
              <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition /><ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Ellipse x:Name="Off" Width="14" Height="14" Stroke="#FF7A7A7A" StrokeThickness="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <Line x:Name="On" X1="0" Y1="0" X2="0" Y2="14" Stroke="#FF7A7A7A" StrokeThickness="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
              </Grid>
            </Border>
            <Border BorderBrush="#FF939393" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="slider" Width="41" Height="27" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0">
              <Border.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                  <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                  <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0" />
                  <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                  <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
                </TransformGroup>
              </Border.RenderTransform>
              <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                  <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0" />
                  <GradientStop Color="#FFCDCDCD" Offset="0.1" />
                  <GradientStop Color="#FFFBFBFB" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
              </Border.Background>
            </Border>
          </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
              <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnUnchecking}" x:Name="OnUnchecking_BeginStoryboard" />
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
              <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnChecking}" x:Name="OnChecking_BeginStoryboard" />
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Setter TargetName="On" Property="Stroke" Value="White" />
            <Setter TargetName="Off" Property="Stroke" Value="White" />
            <!-- Change Orange or Blue color here -->
            <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CheckedOrange}" />
            <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CheckedOrangeBorder}" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <!-- ToDo: Add Style for Isenabled == False -->
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Sorry to sound new (i am!), but having only VS2010, can I get this to work?

Comment: Thanks for the code, for IsEnaled="False" I used: `<Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.4" />` simple and does the job

Comment: For some reason, this exact implementation, at around each 5 clicks, has a bit of a freeze/lag. I am trying to see if it is because of the SplineDoubleKeyFrame.

Comment: How would one make it to be more flexible in terms of sizing? I have managed to set height/width attributes with proper bindings, but animation keeps me away from reaching the final goal as it is Freezable.

Answer (score 13):

A few open source ToggleSwitches:

- [ToggleSwitch](https://github.com/ejensen/toggle-switch-control) looks good, available by NuGet, too.
- [MahApps ToggleSwitch](https://mahapps.com/docs/controls/toggleswitch) is a part of bigger MahApps library of Metro like controls.

Answer (score 2):

I just posted an entry in regards to this which provides a proper sliding action, full configurability and doesn't require to be a fixed size (got annoyed as I couldn't find anything on the web that provided a solution like that).

You can find it here: http://itsallaboutthexaml.blogspot.com/2012/01/variables-in-animation.html

Comment: link is dead, please provide an alternate link or code snipped

Comment: @TimBijnens link isnt dead, it just takes a while to load the page.

Answer (score 0):

I like the nice prototype from arconaut and I added some code to get the border rounded.

You have to remove the "Background" property from the Grid declaration and add this lines between the Grid declaration and the first TextBlock declaration:

```
<Border
    x:Name="back"
    CornerRadius="3,3,3,3"
    BorderThickness="1"
    BorderBrush="#FFC0CCD9"
    >
    <Rectangle Fill="#FFC0CCD9"/>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I set out to accomplish this same task but the examples fell a little short of production code.  For instance what happens if you put text into the control like On/Off or a localized version of the text, answer is you have to define the size of the control because you cannot modify an animation or template triggers after you have rendered the control.  This gives you a one-size-fits-all solution that will not work with localized text.

My solution was to create the template for the control dynamically using the control's Loaded event and the FrameworkElementFactory class.  I have to say it was by far complicated but could be achieved.  Simply put, in your code behind, create a template as described,  setup dependency properties for your on/off text, use the text metrics to determine the control's width, height and animation values.

I'm sorry that I cannot post the solution since it belongs to Avanquest now. :(

Look for it in SystemSuite and Fix-It 12.