# Add CheckBox on Image that Bind on a property On the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using WPF and MVVM to develop photo viewer application ; however, I want to add checkBox on image as 
[this image](https://ibb.co/3h1B05Y)
My application is making some operation on the image before displaying it , these operation take a place in the runtime , however image tag  bind on property called in a viewModel called image as the code shown below:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SliceItemTemplate" DataType="x:Type MyoSENCSlice">
            <Border Name="ListBorder" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" >
                <Viewbox>
                    <Grid>
                        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="ThumbnailImage"  Source="{Binding RepresentativeImage.Image}" Stretch="Uniform" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"/>
                        <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ThumbnailShapes.DisplayThumbnailContours}">

                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <Canvas Name="SliceCanvas" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ThumbnailImage}" 
                                            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ThumbnailImage}">
                                    </Canvas>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

ome threads mentioned that you can not puts a controlContent on images .Moreover , I have tried the answers is this link , but they didn't work.

Any ideas how I can do that

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Some threads mentioned that you can not puts a controlContent on images .Moreover , I have tried the answers is this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014716/image-inside-sliding-checkbox-in-xaml
 , but they didn't work

Comment: Then please [edit] those informations in your question

Comment: I don't follow what you're trying to do with that markup. It makes no sense. You have an image control and on top of that an itemscontrol with a canvas as itemspanel. That can't be right. Your picture shows two images and one has a little white box is presumably the checkbox. Are there always 2 and is it just the last one is supposed to have a checkbox on it.... Or what?

Comment: You can ignore the second one , I want to add checkBox for the first picture